# Swift UTC TimeZone is not UTC

Tags: swift, xcode, timezone, utc, gmt

I have a question about Swift type TimeZone.
I need to get a UTC0 time zone to format my Date object. I'm creating TimeZone object like this.

`let utcTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")`

But when created this object gives me GMT0 time zone. Is this possible to get UTC0 time zone in Swift? Also what is the difference between `GMT (fixed)` and  `GMT (GMT) offset 0` in playground?

Xcode 10.3 Playground
[image]

Comment: How did you get a `GMT (GMT) offset 0` time zone?

Comment: @Sweeper Added screenshot to question.

Answer (score 26):

Technically, there are [*really* subtle differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)) between UTC and GMT (GMT could mean UT1), but the designers of the API thought they are practically the same (which they are), so they made this true:

```
TimeZone(identifier: "UTC") == TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
```

They both represent a timezone with a constant offset of 0.

If you just want to show the letters "UTC" in some output text, use a `DateFormatter`:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss 'UTC'"
print(formatter.string(from: Date()))
```

Or better yet, use a `ISO8601DateFormatter`, which adds a `Z` to the end of the date to indicate that the date time is in UTC:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
print(formatter.string(from: Date()))
```

> Also what is the difference between GMT (fixed) and  GMT (GMT) offset 0 in playground?

The former comes from the Swift `TimeZone` class, and the latter comes from the Objective-C `NSTimeZone` class. One is the bridged version of the other. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone) of `NSTimeZone`,

> use `NSTimeZone` when you need reference semantics or other Foundation-specific behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I've been there, according to google

> There is no time difference between Coordinated Universal Time and Greenwich Mean Time

In other words, GMT is (basically) UTC, so you already have it!

`offset 0` is referring to the timezones offset from UTC/GMT, which is 0, and would be potentially something like 240 if you were in EST (depending on if it's in minutes, hours, milliseconds etc.).

`fixed` on your second line means it's GMT and the offset data is potentially immutable. I wouldn't know without the playground open but I'd try changing the timezone after instancing that and see how if the offset can be changed post assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead of UTC, in some device only setting UTC not working

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-01-23T11:55:00.000Z")
```